# SQL View Question: Conditional calculated columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am having an issue with developing a view for use. This view is a join between three tables - however, not every row will have a value from all three tables - hence the LEFT JOIN. Attached below is the code:

```
SELECT 
    dbs.ID,
    dbs.OrderID,
    dbs.SystemID,
    dbs.SalesOrderNo,
    dbs.[LineNo],
    dbs.OrderQty,
    dbs.ProductionOrder,
    dbs.Workstation,
    ref.Material,
    ref.MaterialDescription,
    dbs.Date,
    dbs.Status,
    dbs.Operator,
    dbs.StartTime,
    dbs.EndTime,
    dbs.TotalTime,
    SUM(del.DelayTime) AS DelTime,
    ref.BuildTime AS CycleTime,
    dbs.TotalTime - SUM(del.DelayTime) AS BuildTime

FROM
    [Booms DBS] AS dbs 
    LEFT JOIN
    [Booms Delay Entry] AS del
    ON dbs.ID = del.ID 
    LEFT JOIN
    [Booms Reference Master] AS ref
    ON dbs.SystemID = ref.SystemID AND dbs.Workstation = ref.Workstation

GROUP BY
    dbs.ID,
    dbs.OrderID,
    dbs.SystemID,
    dbs.SalesOrderNo,
    dbs.[LineNo],
    dbs.OrderQty,
    dbs.ProductionOrder,
    dbs.Workstation,
    ref.Material,
    ref.MaterialDescription,
    dbs.Date,
    dbs.Status,
    dbs.Operator,
    dbs.StartTime,
    dbs.EndTime,
    dbs.TotalTime,
    ref.BuildTime
```

In lines 18 and 20, there are aggregations based on the values of "DelayTime" from a delay table. However, not every record is associated with a delay. "BuildTime" is calculated based off of the "TotalTime" and the "DelayTime" values.

However, it seems like when the 'DelTime' column (sum of DelayTime) is NULL (AKA there is no delay associated), "BuildTime" will not populate. Is there some kind of conditional I can add that states that when 'DelTime' is NULL, just populate the "BuildTime" based off "TotalTime"?

Comment: Use `SUM(isnull(del.DelayTime,0))`. See if that works for you.

Comment: That worked. Awesome, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add two values that could be `NULL`, then use `coalesce()` on the values.  So:

```
dbs.TotalTime - coalesce(SUM(del.DelayTime), 0) AS BuildTime
```

There is no need to `coalesce()` as an argument to `sum()`, because `sum()` (like most aggregation functions) ignores `null` values.